# summary() function not printing correctly

Tags: r, summary

This might be a very lame question, but I cannot really figure out what's going. Normally if I called this function:

```
summary(VLTcog$per ~ VLTcog$Cognate)
```

The output that I got was:

VLTcog$per    N=90

+--------------+--+--+----------+
|              |  |N |VLTcog$per|
+--------------+--+--+----------+
|VLTcog$Cognate|C |48|74.42708  |
|              |NC|42|56.42857  |
+--------------+--+--+----------+
|Overall       |  |90|66.02778  |
+--------------+--+--+----------+

Now, if I do the same, the only output it gives me is:
  Length   Class    Mode
      3 formula    call
str of my data
str(VLTcog)
'data.frame':   90 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Item     : Factor w/ 90 levels "1 acquiesce",..: 86 16 30 62 28 53 26 83 51 65 ...
 $ Cognate  : Factor w/ 2 levels "C","NC": 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 ...
 $ Frequency: Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ per      : num  100 67.5 95 82.5 87.5 67.5 95 40 87.5 87.5 ...

Comment: Basically, if I called that summary function, I used to get a nice chart where means, counts were displayed by grouping variable and the total... Now, I only get this output    Length   Class    Mode 
      3 formula    call   and nothing else...

Comment: This is the problem, I always use the same libraries and I loaded them all, restarted Rstudio, updated Rstudio and still nothing...

Comment: You must have had a `summary()` function loaded from some package or source file before. It will be basically impossible (or take some *very* lucky guessing) to figure out where it came from and why you don't have it any more.

Comment: @Ben, thanks a lot for replying. The problem is that I have a list of packages that I always use and load. The latest one was TAM, when it was still working... then I installed ltm... however I cannot really link the two problems together... No new packages should change how a function works, which is part of the basic package...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `summary` behaviour was coming from `Hmisc::summary.formula` (I used `library(sos); findFn("summary.formula")` to figure this out ...)

In a clean R session:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 1:10
summary(y~x)
## Length   Class    Mode 
##   3 formula    call
```

Now load `Hmisc`:

```
library(Hmisc)
packageVersion("Hmisc")
## [1] ‘4.0.0’
summary(y~x)
## y     N= 10 
## 
## +-------+------+--+---+
## |       |      |N |y  |
## +-------+------+--+---+
## |x      |[1, 4)| 3|2.0|
## |       |[4, 6)| 2|4.5|
## |       |[6, 9)| 3|7.0|
## |       |[9,10]| 2|9.5|
## +-------+------+--+---+
## |Overall|      |10|5.5|
## +-------+------+--+---+
```

So I suggest you see how things go if you try this in a session with *only* `Hmisc` loaded, then try out other packages to see if one of them masks the `summary.formula` method ...

Comment: you a are a huge star! :) That was the reason. Thanks a lot!